# How can I propose an edit to the help center on " What topics can I ask about here?"

Tags: discussion

I would like to propose that the Help Center topic **What topics can I ask about here?** be eddited to the following:

---

## What topics can I ask about here?

Please [look around](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

### This is a list of what is **on topic** on Data Science Stack Exchange:

Data Science can be described as the integration of **Machine Learning** (Math and Statistics) and **Programming** with the **Knowledge of a Specific Field** to **find and visualize** solutions in that Field using **Data**.

#### Machine Learning Topics:

- **Questions on pros and cons of certain Machine Learning models. Example:**

  - What are the benefits of using GELU and Leaky-RELU over RELU for object detection?
- **Questions on feature engineering, feature selection and dimensionality reduction. Example:**

  - When is it suitable to apply L1 regularization for feature selection?
- **Questions for recommendation on models for specific problems. Example:**

  - Given Facebook Likes, is there an ML technique to predict age and gender?

#### Programming related to datascience:

- **Questions on the pros and cons in the use of libraries, languages or frameworks for Data Science. Example:**

  - When executing an ARIMA model in Spark, what are the pros and cons of using Python instead of R?
- **Question on the available implementations for given models. Example:**

  - Where can I find a C implementation of CNNs for mobile devices?

#### Data Visualization and Explanation:

- **Question of best practices and best ways to visualize certain kind of data. Example:**

  - I would like to produce a infographic on the 'Brexit' referendum. Given public opinion data across the UK, what are some meaningful techniques to visualize it in a dashboard?

#### Field Specific information with direct relation to Data Science:

- **Questions of field understanding that can be used for modeling. Example:**

  - What Image Processing procedures may help solving object detection in dark environments?

#### Questions on Data Science

- Career related, definitions and interpretations of terms in Data Science

### For off-topic questions

If your question is not specifically on-topic for Data Science Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. For example, questions here are frequently also suitable, or more suitable, on one of:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (Programming Related Questions)

  - Why does TensorFlow returns ValueError for...
- [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) (Data Set Requests)
- [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (stats.stackexchange.com)

If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area 51, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

---

Edit: Examples removed to reduce size:

- While using Keras, my model crashes and gives me this exception
- Is it possible to implement a LSTM on a device with 128 KB of memory?
- Given process monitoring data arriving every 10ms, what statistical tool should - I use to best characterize a change in the process - mean? a distribution?
- How can I encode text for regression algorithm
- Which kind of algorithm is usually better for tabular data? Neural Networks of Decision Trees?
- What are the benefits of using CNNs instead of Recursive layers to deal with spatially related data?

Comment: This is the correct place to propose the change since mods can edit that page, and also the correct place to discuss the proposal if some users disagree/want to give feedback/improvement.

Comment: good stuff thank you! more feedback from others would be appreciated :-) I think it might be a little bit long for some people's attention span. can we make it more crisp?

Comment: Maybe using just 1 example per topic